# IDXGISwapChain::GetCurrentBackBufferIndex returns wrong index

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12

I am getting the error

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandQueue::ExecuteCommandLists: A command list, which writes to a swapchain back buffer, may only be executed when that back buffer is the back buffer that will be presented during the next call to Present*. Such a back buffer is also referred to as the "current back buffer"

However, I am using the index returned from `IDXGISwapChain::GetCurrentBackBufferIndex`? So what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling `IDXGISwapChain1::Present` before calling `ID3D12CommandQueue::ExecuteCommandLists`:

```cpp
auto index = IDXGISwapChain::GetCurrentBackBufferIndex() // gets index
IDXGISwapChain::Present() // increments backbuffer, makes index stale
ID3D12CommandQueue::ExecuteCommandLists() // BOOM, commandList used stale index
```